# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns true, but Conventions.AuthorizeFolder still bounces the user as unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I'm working on a simple web app using C#, .NET Core 3.0, and Razor. I have a folder (`/Admin`) that I want to restrict access to. There are no authorization groups; you're either authorized or you're not.

I've hit a snag while trying to implement this as noted in the title.

As far as I can tell, I've got the login method working. I call `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` and have confirmed that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is `true` thereafter. However, the now-authenticated user still cannot access the `/Admin` pages. They are bounced back to the login page by `options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin")`. The login page sees the user as authenticated and the result is a redirect loop.

I've been using the following resources:

- [Razor Pages authorization conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
- [Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Can someone help illuminate where exactly I've gone wrong?

(I've significantly reduced this code to what I assume to be related and necessary, but if you feel I've left out something important, please let me know.)

**Startup.cs**

```csharp
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
    services.AddTransient<IAuthService, AuthService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddDbContext<Entities.WeddingContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"])
    );

    services.AddRazorPages(options => {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin");
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Admin/Login");
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/Admin/Login"; });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToWwwPermanent());
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

**Pages/Admin/Login.cshtml.cs**

```csharp
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    if (_authService.IsLoggedIn())
        return RedirectToPage("Index");

    await _authService.LoginAsync("testemail@test.com", "testpassword", true);
    return Page();
}
```

**AuthService.cs**

```csharp
public async Task LoginAsync(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
    var user = _db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
    if (user == null) throw new Exception("Email not found.");

    var verification = VerifyPassword(user, password);
    if (verification == PasswordVerificationResult.Failed)  
        throw new Exception("Incorrect password.");
    if (verification == PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded)
        RehashPassword(user, password);

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, email));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email));
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await _contextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = rememberMe });
}

public bool IsLoggedIn()
{
    return _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out after doing a line-by-line comparison with the [sample code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization/samples/3.x/AuthorizationSample/Startup.cs).

In the *Startup.cs* `Configure` method, `app.UseAuthentication()` **must come *before*** `app.UseAuthorization()`.

Swapping these two lines resolved the issue.